# Flutter Dart - How to create text field validations and conditions?

Tags: flutter, dart, validation, controller, textfield

I'm creating the 'Create Account' page. It contains the following text fields "First Name, Last Name, Email, Password". How do create validation conditions like below?

1. Display the text 'This field is required' in an empty field
2. In the email field 'Enter a valid email' and 'This email is already taken'

Code:

```
Column(
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 35),
                child: Container(
                  width: 310,
                  child: TextFormField(
                    controller: _firstnameController,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      label: RichText(
                        text: TextSpan(
                            text: 'First Name',
                            style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                                color: Color(0xffc1c1c1),
                                fontSize: 17,
                                letterSpacing: 0.4),
                            children: const [
                              TextSpan(
                                  text: ' *',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.red,
                                    fontSize: 21,
                                  )),
                            ]),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
                child: Container(
                  width: 310,
                  child: TextFormField(
                    controller: _lastnameController,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      label: RichText(
                        text: TextSpan(
                            text: 'Last Name',
                            style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                                color: Color(0xffc1c1c1),
                                fontSize: 17,
                                letterSpacing: 0.4),
                            children: const [
                              TextSpan(
                                  text: ' *',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.red,
                                    fontSize: 21,
                                  )),
                            ]),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
                child: Container(
                  width: 310,
                  child: TextFormField(
                    controller: _emailController,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      label: RichText(
                        text: TextSpan(
                            text: 'Enter Your Email',
                            style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                                color: Color(0xffc1c1c1),
                                fontSize: 17,
                                letterSpacing: 0.4),
                            children: const [
                              TextSpan(
                                  text: ' *',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.red,
                                    fontSize: 21,
                                  )),
                            ]),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
                child: Container(
                  width: 310,
                  child: TextFormField(
                    controller: _passwordController,
                    obscureText: true,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      label: RichText(
                        text: TextSpan(
                            text: 'Enter Your Password',
                            style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                                color: Color(0xffc1c1c1),
                                fontSize: 17,
                                letterSpacing: 0.4),
                            children: const [
                              TextSpan(
                                  text: ' *',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.red,
                                    fontSize: 21,
                                  )),
                            ]),
                      ),
                      suffixIcon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.eye_slash_fill, size: 25),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```

Comment: Use Form Widget and you can write the validator function inside TextFormField.

https://www.topcoder.com/thrive/articles/form-validation-in-flutter

Answer (score 0):

To add validation conditions to your text fields, you can use the validator property of TextFormField.

**Validation**

```
validator: (value) {
        if (value.isEmpty) {
          return 'This field is required';
        }
        if (!RegExp(r'^[\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4}$').hasMatch(value)) {
          return 'Enter a valid email';
        }
        // add your own logic to check if email is already taken
        return null;
      },
```

**For Eg (Full Source Code):**

```
Column(
  children: [
    Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 35),
      child: Container(
        width: 310,
        child: TextFormField(
          controller: _firstnameController,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            label: RichText(
              text: TextSpan(
                  text: 'First Name',
                  style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                      color: Color(0xffc1c1c1),
                      fontSize: 17,
                      letterSpacing: 0.4),
                  children: const [
                    TextSpan(
                        text: ' *',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.red,
                          fontSize: 21,
                        )),
                  ]),
            ),
          ),
          validator: (value) {
            if (value.isEmpty) {
              return 'This field is required';
            }
            return null;
          },
        ),
      ),
    ),
    Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
      child: Container(
        width: 310,
        child: TextFormField(
          controller: _lastnameController,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            label: RichText(
              text: TextSpan(
                  text: 'Last Name',
                  style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                      color: Color(0xffc1c1c1),
                      fontSize: 17,
                      letterSpacing: 0.4),
                  children: const [
                    TextSpan(
                        text: ' *',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.red,
                          fontSize: 21,
                        )),
                  ]),
            ),
          ),
          validator: (value) {
            if (value.isEmpty) {
              return 'This field is required';
            }
            return null;
          },
        ),
      ),
    ),
    Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
      child: Container(
        width: 310,
        child: TextFormField(
          controller: _emailController,
          keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            label: RichText(
              text: TextSpan(
                  text: 'Enter Your Email',
                  style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                      color: Color(0xffc1c1c1),
                      fontSize: 17,
                      letterSpacing: 0.4),
                  children: const [
                    TextSpan(
                        text: ' *',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.red,
                          fontSize: 21,
                        )),
                  ]),
            ),
          ),
          validator: (value) {
            if (value.isEmpty) {
              return 'This field is required';
            }
            if (!RegExp(r'^[\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4}$').hasMatch(value)) {
              return 'Enter a valid email';
            }
            // add your own logic to check if email is already taken
            return null;
          },
        ),
      ),
    ),
    Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
      child: Container(
        width: 310,
        child: TextFormField(
          controller: _passwordController,
          obscureText: true,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            label: RichText(
              text: TextSpan(
                  text: 'Enter Your Password',
                  style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                      color: Color(0xffc1c1c1),
                      fontSize: 17,
                      letterSpacing: 0.4),
                  children: const [
                    TextSpan(
                        text: ' *',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.red,
                          fontSize: 21,
                                  )),
                            ]),
                      ),
                      suffixIcon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.eye_slash_fill, size: 25),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```